# Hide form after submit successful

Tags: php

Currently I have a contact form working, but I need to hide the form itself after it was send successful. I was thinking of hitting a javascript call when the 'succes' message is run, but I don't know how to do this.

How can I hide the form, but keep the succes message if it's completed?

Thanks in advance!

```
 <?php
  //response generation function

  $response = "";

  //function to generate response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){

    global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
    else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

  }

  //response messages
  $not_human       = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Verificatie incorrect.</div>";
  $missing_content = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>U heeft niet alle verplichte velden ingevuld</div>";
  $email_invalid   = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Incorrect e-mail adres.</div>";
  $message_unsent  = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Bericht niet verzonden. Probeer opnieuw.</div>";
  $message_sent    = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Bedankt, wij nemen binnenkort contact met u op</div>";

  //user posted variables
  $name = $_POST['message_name'];
  $email = $_POST['message_email'];
  $phone = $_POST['message_phone'];
  $message = $_POST['message_text'];
  $human = $_POST['message_human'];

  $totalmessage = "
     Naam:       $name \n
     Telefoonnummer:      $phone \n
     E-mail:      $email \n
     Bericht:    $message \n ";

  //php mailer variables
  $to = "$curauth->user_email";
  $subject = "Bel mij terug";
  $headers = 'From: email@email.com' . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: email@email.com' . "\r\n" .
      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  if(!$human == 0){
    if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
    else {

      //validate email
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
      else //email is valid
      {
        //validate presence of name and message
        if(empty($name)){
          my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        }
        else //ready to go!
        {
          $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $totalmessage, $headers);
          if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
          else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>

<div id="respond">
  <?php echo $response; ?>
  <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Uw naam (verplicht) <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_phone">Uw Telefoonnummer (verplicht) <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="message_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_phone']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_email">Uw e-mail adres: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_text">Uw vraag: <span></span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_human">Verificatie: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" value="1">
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Fester That one is javascript, there is no javascript in this question, so it's not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Blaatpraat  Yes, I think the javascript tag needs removing from this post.  It's all HTML & PHP.

Comment: @Fester: good point, let's remove that tag

Comment: @Fester: I'm not the OP, I'm a responder here :-)

Comment: A javascript solution wound't be even possible, as the page state is lost,.  You could only do a javascript solution if the submitting was done with Ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nee, ik bel je niet terug :-)

You can do this by not showing the form when your mail is sent.
Because you already show a message, this should be enough:

```
<?php
if (!isset($sent) || !$sent) {
?>
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Uw naam (verplicht) <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_phone">Uw Telefoonnummer (verplicht) <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="message_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_phone']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_email">Uw e-mail adres: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_text">Uw vraag: <span></span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_human">Verificatie: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" value="1">
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

So putting the form inside an if statement.

Comment: Terrific! 

Just had to put the "  <?php echo $response; ?> " outside the if =)

(have to wait few minutes to mark this as correct)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.none {display:none;}
.block {display:block;}
```

Add this to your code:

```
<?php
//response generation function
$hide_form = 'block';
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
...

else //ready to go!
{
$hide_form = 'none';
...
```

In the `<form>` tag put:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" class="<?php echo $hide_form;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the form pretty much as it is (although I would move the php dealing with the post to a different url, then redirect back if not an AJAX request), then it will deal with the request if Javascript is turned off in the user's browser.

Then add the following javascript (adding in the save url):

```js
$('#my-form').submit(function(evt){
 // stop form submitting
 evt.preventDefault();

 $.ajax(function(){
   method: "POST",
   url: "[ADD_SAVE_URL]]",
    success(function(data){
     // debug response
     console.log(data);
      
      $('#response-message').html(response.message);
      if (response.success){
        $('#my-form').hide();
      }
    }),
    fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
     // debug response
     console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
      
      $('#response-message').html('Ajax error!');
    })
  });

});
```

```html
<div id="respond">
  <div id="response-message"><?php echo $response; ?></div>div>

  <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" id="my-form">
    <p><label for="name">Uw naam (verplicht) <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_phone">Uw Telefoonnummer (verplicht) <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="message_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_phone']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_email">Uw e-mail adres: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_text">Uw vraag: <span></span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_human">Verificatie: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" value="1">
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```